# Why does this code for accessing a parent directory not work in Matlab?

Tags: macos, matlab

I am trying this code:

```
RENDER4CNN_ROOT = fullfile(mfilename('fullpath'),'../../../');
PASCAL3D_DIR = fullfile(RENDER4CNN_ROOT, 'datasets/pascal3d/');
addpath(fullfile(PASCAL3D_DIR, 'VDPM'));
addpath(fullfile(PASCAL3D_DIR, 'Annotation_tools'));
addpath(RENDER4CNN_ROOT);
```

It gives me "Warning: Name is nonexistent or not a directory:" and I can't cd either.

The code is a bit older than my Matlab version. What's the problem? Is this code written for a different OS?

**Edit**

`ls -al` outputs

```
drwxr-xr-x@  9 Goldname  staff   288 Oct  8  2016 .
drwxr-xr-x@ 14 Goldname  staff   448 Oct  8  2016 ..
-rwxr-xr-x@  1 Goldname  staff  5686 Oct  8  2016 get_voc12train_truncation_stats.m
-rwxr-xr-x@  1 Goldname  staff  1847 Oct  8  2016 get_voc12train_view_stats.m
drwxr-xr-x@ 65 Goldname  staff  2080 Jun 15 15:27 matlab_kde_package
-rwxr-xr-x@  1 Goldname  staff  2684 Oct  8  2016 run_sampling.m
-rwxr-xr-x@  1 Goldname  staff  2047 Oct  8  2016 sample_truncations.m
-rwxr-xr-x@  1 Goldname  staff  2954 Oct  8  2016 sample_viewpoints.m
-rwxr-xr-x@  1 Goldname  staff   442 Jun 15 17:15 setup_path.m
```

From what I can see, `mfilename` is used incorrectly? It outputs the directory and file, which my commandline cannot cd into, even with ".." attached to the end.

I'm using MacOS. It appears that the commandline cannot do something like

```
cd /directory/file/..
```

Comment: If you're directory is located in root which might not be the case then ```cd /directory/file/..``` will work, however if it is located somewhere else such as in your home directory then you want to do ```cd ~/directory/file```

Comment: Also I think you should first open your project directory where the file ```setup_path.m``` is located, and open a terminal in that directory, and run the command  ```echo $PWD```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mfilename('fullpath')` outputs the name of the M-file that runs its, with full path. In your case, from the comments, this is `/Foo/RenderForCNN-master/render_pipeline/kde/setup_path`. `setup_path` is the name of the M-file (minus the `.m` extension).

```
fullfile(mfilename('fullpath'),'../../../')
```

therefore creates the path `/Foo/RenderForCNN-master/render_pipeline/kde/setup_path/../../../`. This is not a valid path, because `setup_path` does not exist. If we were to add the file extension it would read `/Foo/RenderForCNN-master/render_pipeline/kde/setup_path.m/../../../`, which would also not be a valid path.

You need to remove the name of the M-file from the output of `mfilename`:

```
fullfile(fileparts(mfilename('fullpath')),'../../../')
```

You now need to make sure that the intended directory is actually reached this way, it is possible that one of the `..` is no longer needed.

Comment: Should the old commands have worked on different operating systems? This is weird because I got the code off a project from github.

Comment: @Goldname: It is possible that a different OS decodes a path differently.

Answer (score 0):

Print this variable `RENDER4CNN_ROOT` and check if you can manually cd into it.

or

run `cd RENDER4CNN_ROOT`

If you receive an error, then you must modify this argument `'../../../'` accordingly based on your script location.

You are receiving the warning due to `addpath()` as it is not able to find the path given by `fullfile(PASCAL3D_DIR, 'VDPM')`

Comment: Yes, cd doesn't work. It says "Cannot CD to...(Name is nonexistent or not a directory)."

Comment: No, the parent directory exists. In fact, changing the first line of code to ../ also doesn't work.

Comment: @Goldname, Can you show the output of both ```mfilename('fullpath')``` and ```RENDER4CNN_ROOT``` ?

Comment: Output of Render4CNN_ROOT gives: '/Foo/RenderForCNN-master/render_pipeline/kde/setup_path/../../../'

Comment: mfilename('fullpath') returns

ans =

  0×0 empty char array

Comment: Because mfilename will return the file name of the script

Comment: Oh Sorry I didn't know, I just typed those lines into Matlab command to tell you the result, but yes I am running them as a script.

Comment: Removing the semicolon in the first line gives: RENDER4CNN_ROOT =

    '/Foo/RenderForCNN-master/render_pipeline/kde/setup_path/../../../'

Comment: In terminal, try ```cd /Foo/RenderForCNN-master/render_pipeline/kde/setup_path/../../../```

Comment: Interesting, it's also giving no such file or directory

Comment: It appears the final "setup_path" folder doesn't exist. Do you know why mfilename is outputting this?

Comment: @Goldname, you need to update your question with more details , like output of ```ls -al``` in your working directory and its parent directory (note: check if you have permissions too)

Comment: `pwd` is not equivalent to `fileparts(mfilename('fullpath'))`.

Comment: @CrisLuengo, Can you explain why ?, I tested it in a sample script and it returned the working directory of the script, Probably with the script name it should be ```[pwd,'/',mfilename]```

Comment: `pwd` always returns the working directory (==current directory). The working directory is independent of where the script is. If you run a script that is in the working directory, then of course these two things do the same. But the script can be anywhere on the MATLAB path. When you run a script then `pwd` will return the working directory and not the directory where the script is.